# Bootstrapper DisplayRootFor<MV>() Exception: No parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, mvvm, ninject, caliburn.micro, bootstrapper

I need to create a simple application, where in `MainViewModel` something happens during initialization.

When I try to run my code, the exception occurs on line             `DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();` in `AppBootstrapper`:

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**Bootstrapper:**

```
using System;
using Ninject;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace ChartsDisplayer2016
{ 
    public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
        }
        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            kernel.Inject(instance);
        }
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(sender, e);
            DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ChartsDisplayer2016.Core.Charts.ViewModels;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace ChartsDisplayer2016.Core.Main.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel: Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
        private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

        MainViewModel()
        {
            //something important;
        }
        MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
            IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
            this.windowManager = windowManager;

            //something important
        }
    }
}
```

**MainView:**

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             x:Class="ChartsDisplayer2016.Core.Main.Views.MainView"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I get rid of this exception?

EDIT:

Changed acces modifier of `MainViewModel` to `public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainViewModel` class and constructor have no access specifier so it defaults to private.

```
    namespace ChartsDisplayer2016.Core.Main.ViewModels
    {

        public class MainViewModel: Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
        {

            private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
            private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;


            public MainViewModel()
            {
                //something important;
            }
            public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
                                 IWindowManager windowManager)
            {
                this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
                this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
                this.windowManager = windowManager;

                //something important
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. Unfortunately making `MainViewModel` `public` didn't work - the exception is still the same.

Comment: Did you make the constructor public?

Comment: No, I didn't. Now with public constructors it works fine. Thank You very much :)